# Examples for Beam Window Into with Aggregation and event Timestamp

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I simply need some good examples of how to perform the following in Beam (Dataflow) using Python:

- Streaming
- Aggregation (eg, sum, count, whatever) based upon a key
- Using Windowing (simple fixed windowing without triggers is fine)
- Using the *event timestamp which is in the event data* for windowing

---

Specifically, I cannot seem to find *any* examples where I have a data field of, say `time_created` in my incoming dataset which I use for the timestamp (eg, something like `window.TimestampedValue(element, element["time_created"])`), and then I am able to aggregate on that timestamped value.

My problem is that I do not understand how to:

- Aggregate on that timestamp *as a window* (eg, a `WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(120))` function that will capture all elements within the 2 minute window
- While being able to somehow *emit* that window timestamp
- And be able to group by key.

I am unable to emit the timestamp related to the window.  I can get everything to work, as long as I am not interested in knowing the associated window timestamp. But I do want to know this.

Comment: Actually, I just figured out my problem: I can remove the timestamp column, then groupby + sum, then add the timestamp back in from the windowing information.  Once I have everything working, I'll post an answer to my own question in case others see this.